# Python custom sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list of objects like this:

```
my_list = [obj1,obj2,obj3, ...]
```

Each object has some data like:

```
obj = {
    'id':1,
    'name':'Some name',
    'value': 'Some value',
    'category':'A'
}
```

The category options are:  `CATEGORY = {'A','B','C','D'}`

Is it possible to sort the list somehow to display data in sequence like:

```
    my_sordet_list =  ['all in C categ', 'all in B categ', 'all in D categ','all in A categ']
```

So the question is: How can I explain to the program that I want it to **be sorted in a strict custom sequence?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a lookup dictionary for your custom ordering:

```
>>> category_order = {'C': 0, 'B': 1, 'D': 2, 'A': 3}
>>> my_sorted_list = sorted(mylist, key=lambda o: category_order[o['category']])
```

`my_sorted_list` will be sorted, as you desire.